# Jasper report generates rich text in report

Tags: java, formatting, jasper-reports

I have rich text saved in database. I also want to show rich text in report too like underline, bold, font-size or font-face e.t.c

```
String[] columnNames = {"#", "Reference No.", "Name", "From", "Desc"};
System.out.println("viewList.size() ="+viewList.size());

String[][] data = new String[viewList.size()+documentViewList.size()][5];
int counter=0;
for(int i=0; i < viewList.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j< 5; j++){
        if(j==0)data[i][j]=(counter++)+"";
        if(j==1)data[i][j]=viewList.get(i).getFile().getId();
        if(j==2)data[i][j]=viewList.get(i).getReferenceNo().toString();
        if(j==3)data[i][j]=viewList.get(i).getShortText();
        if(j==4)data[i][j]=viewList.get(i).getDescription();
    }
}
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
```

Here on this line it contain some rich text. But it is showing as it is in data base. e.g.

```
if(j==4)data[i][j]=viewList.get(i).getDescription();
```

**Database value:**

```
 <p><u>asdasdads asd a</u></p>
```

I want this text to be under lined.

Answer (score 1):

Set `markup` property of the element where you display the value to "styled". If you create JRXML programmatically, use [setMarkup ("styled")](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRCommonText.html#setMarkup%28java.lang.String%29).

**EDIT**: Actually, you might also try "html" and "rtf". "styled" is what we use in our application, so that was an automatic answer, sort of.

Comment: This link is blocked in our domain kindly give any other link for help

Comment: You should then complain to however blocked it then. It's a link to official JR javadoc and blocking such stuff is kinda unproductive in a programming company.